# How to force users to authenticate to get IP adress from DHCP?

Tags: dhcp, network-access, pfsense, authentication, network

Can You help me !! 
I want to force users to authentificate to get IP from DHCP-server (win server) if not they can't get ip @ adress !! even they are connected to network

Comment: There are products that do this, but they are expensive and complex to set up.  What will you do if a user sets their own static IP?

Comment: What is this products ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a standard to achieve this: 802.1X.

Basically the switch request authentication from the computer, then contact an authentication server to validate the credentials and depending on the answer the switch will deny or allow access.

There's further possible options, like placing the host in a guest vlan if not authenticated or placing the host in a specific VLAN depending of some of the user properties.

Obviously your switch must support 802.1X and you need an authentication server (usually a radius server).

In a windows environment, the Network Policy Server role can act as the authentication server. It is natively integrated with Active Directory.